# Como instanciar objetos na memória compartilhada?

Tags: c++, thread, processo

Eu tenho uma aplicação na qual há vários modos de paralelização. Entretanto, quando vou paralelizar através de *fork()* a barreira não é compartilhada entre os processos, há alguma diferença do Shm em lidar com a instanciação via new ou há outra forma de prover o compartilhamento dessa barreira?

OBS: não sei se faz diferença, mas a *barrier* é um objeto *static* na classe pai.

```
#include "ProcessMode.hpp"

ProcessMode::ProcessMode(IndexGenerator *index_generator_template, numerical *numerical_array, short number_of_processors)
    : ParalelizationMode(index_generator_template, numerical_array, number_of_processors) {

    // Sharing the barrier for use among the processes
    int ptr_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(Barrier), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    ParalelizationMode::barrier = (Barrier*) shmat(ptr_id, NULL, 0);
    ParalelizationMode::barrier = new Barrier(number_of_processors);
}

void ProcessMode::run() {
    pid_t pid;
    int id = 0;

    // Create processes
    for (short i = 1; i < number_of_processors; i++) {
        pid = fork();

        if(pid > 0) {
        continue;
        }
        else {
            id = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    calculate(new Calculator(numerical_array, index_generator_template->clone(id)));
    ParalelizationMode::barrier->wait();

    if (pid == 0) exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o erro. O shmget por si só já "cria" um objeto na memória compartilhada. Corrigindo o erro de atribuição que cometi anteriormente, basta fazer uma função que inicialize esse objeto, como se fosse um set nas propriedades, já que o shmget não recebe nenhum parâmetro para "instanciar o objeto". Solução:

```
ProcessMode::ProcessMode(IndexGenerator *index_generator_template, numerical *numerical_array, short number_of_processors)
    : ParalelizationMode(index_generator_template, numerical_array, number_of_processors) {

    int id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(Barrier), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    ParalelizationMode::barrier = (Barrier*) shmat(id, NULL, 0);
    barrier->initSharedBarrier(number_of_processors);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Repare que o atributo estático da classe pai `ParalelizationMode::barrier` está sendo sobreescrito imediatamente após a chamda de `shmat()`:

```
...
ParalelizationMode::barrier = (Barrier*) shmat(ptr_id, NULL, 0);
ParalelizationMode::barrier = new Barrier(number_of_processors);
...
```

Ao fazer isso, o ponteiro `void *` que foi retornado por `shmat()` é perdido, fazendo com que a chamada da função não tenha efeito algum!

Sugiro a implementação de uma classe filha de `Barrier` chamada `BarrierSharedMemory`, que é a especialização de uma *barrier* utilizando a memória compartilhada.

Essa classe filha será responsável por encapsular as chamadas de `shmat()` e `shmget()`, veja só o exemplo:

```
class BarrierSharedMemory : public Barrier {
     public:
         BarrierSharedMemory( int );
         virtual ~BarrierSharedMemory( void );
     private:
         int m_id;
         void * m_ptr_shm;
};

// ...

BarrierSharedMemory::BarrierSharedMemory( int n )
      : Barrier( n )
{
    this->m_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(Barrier), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    this->m_ptr_shm = shmat(this->m_id, NULL, 0);
}
```

Possibilitando reescrever o construtor de `ProcessMode` da seguinte forma:

```
ProcessMode::ProcessMode(IndexGenerator *index_generator_template, numerical *numerical_array, short number_of_processors)
    : ParalelizationMode(index_generator_template, numerical_array, number_of_processors) {

    ParalelizationMode::barrier = new BarrierSharedMemory(number_of_processors);

}
```

Comment: Testei a solução e ela infelizmente não funcionou. Quando coloco um printf dentro da função wait() o valor do contador da barreira permanece inalterado em ambos os processos, indicando que não houve o compartilhamento. A barreira normal com outros métodos de paralelização funciona corretamente, os prints mostram valores sendo decrementados.